# Normal subgroup induces inclusion on Normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra

Someone told me that the following proposition is true. If $H\trianglelefteq G$ are both subgroups of a group $K$, then $N_{K}(G)\subset N_{K}(H)$, where $N_K(\cdot)$ denotes the normalizer of a group in $K$. I am starting to doubt this is true, since I am not able to prove it. Any information on this proposition would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\;H\lhd K\;$ then the claim is (almost) trivially true, but otherwise it is not. For example, take

$$H:=\{(1)\,,\,(12)(34)\}\lhd G:=\{(1)\,,\,(12)(34)\,,\,(13)(24)\,,\,(14)(23)\}\le K:=A_4$$

Here, *also* $\;G\lhd A_4=K\;$ , so $\;N_K(G)=K\;$ , but of course $\;K\rlap{\;\,/}\le N_K(H)\;$ , since $\;H\;$ is *not* normal in $\;K\;$ ...